# jQuery -> Change Window.href

Tags: javascript, window, href

How would I use jQuery to redirect the page to teh base page + some string?

Specifically, I need to set the window.href = current page **without** params + 'SomeString';

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:
`window.location.href = window.location.pathname + 'SomeString';`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `window.location.pathname' instead of `window.location.path' ?  Other than that bit, I'd say that's the best answer.  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var loc = window.location + '';
window.href = loc.replace('(\?(.+))','') + str;
```